# How did Palpatine get the name "Sidious"?

Tags: star-wars, sith, darth-sidious

Based on this [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/152310/when-did-the-name-sidious-first-appear) about Palpatine's first name being Sheev, I have a follow up question about Sidious being his Sith name. When he gave the Sith name to his apprentices Dooku and Anakin he bestowed it; Darth Tyranus and Darth Vader respectively.

Going back at the question, **did it also happen to Palpatine when he became a Sith?**

In other words, did his master Darth Plagueis bestow him the name Darth Sidious or did Sidious get his name when he killed Hego Damask?

Is there any evidence from the novel by James Luceno "Darth Plagueis" that answers the question?

Comment: What makes you think it wasn't bestowed by Plagueis in exactly the same way "Vader" was bestowed by Sidious?

Comment: because when Sidious killed Hego, My mind was, Did Palpatine get the name "Sidoius" from himself? OR Was he already Darth Sidious at the time when he killed Hego Damask?

Comment: @TheWitchKingofAngmar he was probably already Darth Sidoius, just like how Darth Vader had been Darth Vader for years prior to killing Sidoius

Comment: I fixed/improved the grammar and punctuation a bit and fixed several typos. Please check and make sure I didn't alter the meaning of your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

His name was chosen by his mentor Darth Plagueis, presumably because of his in***sidious*** nature.

> Plagueis planted his hands on his hips and laughed without mirth. *“And of what possible use do you think a person of your nature would be to the Jedi Order? You’re heartless, ambitious, arrogant, **insidious**, and without shame or empathy. More, you’re a murderer.”* He held Palpatine’s hooded gaze and watched the youth’s hands clench in fists of rage. *“Careful, boy,”* he said after a moment. *“You are not the only being in this plush stateroom with the power to kill.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Darth Plagueis by James Luceno](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Plagueis_(novel))</sup></sub>

and

> Palpatine stared at the floor, then genuflected, uttering, *“It is my will to join my destiny forever with the Order of the Sith Lords.”*
> Plagueis extended his left hand to touch him on the crown of the head. *“Then it is done. **From this day forward, the truth of you, now and forever more, will be Sidious.”***